# Facebook Search API Untrusted Connection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to search the Facebook API from my application using javascript FB.api(url, success function) and the JSON object that comes back contains the error: "Search queries are unsupported for this connection."

The url I'm using is: "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Bamboo&type=page&access_token=", which works when I'm testing it in browser

Why is my search unsupported???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your url. You only put your graph api command in the url parameter, thus the "https://graph.facebook.com" shouldn't be included.

For using the search call,

```
var urlCall = "/search?q=Bamboo&type=page&access_token=";
FB.api(urlCall, function(response) {
  //you code to execute     
});
```

and not the following

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Bamboo&type=page&access_token="
```

Comment: This solved my problem. But how about this method: $.ajax({ url:  'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Bamboo&type=page', sucess: function (response) { alert(response); } }); This does not work either.

Comment: I am not familiar with $.Ajax, perhaps jquery? When I clicked on your link I got the error: "message": "Unsupported type, page'". I then took the single quote off the type=page, and I then got a json response. Perhaps a typo?

Maybe try this: $.ajax({ url: "graph.facebook.com/search?q=Bamboo&type=page";, sucess: function (response) { alert(response); } });    ???

Comment: I have tried with double quotes but I don't get any response. It would be nice to understand why:D